Customizing a Parameterized SQL Query in Excel VBA
I am new to VBA, and even newer to ODBC connections and SQL. I am making a spreadsheet that to the end user is just a button that says "Go".
Currently when the button is pressed, the spreadsheet uses a Microsoft Query to create the ODBC connection. Following the connection being established it pulls a series of columns of data and will manipulate them to make them readable for the end user. The problem is that the ODBC database is so massively large that if I do not pass parameters to this connection, it would take hours to load (Literally millions of rows of data, more than 40 years of multiple large industrial sites).
So, I have modified the connection, so the command text prompts for input as follows:
WHERE (SAP_ORDER.WERKS='G202') AND (SAP_ORDER.GSTRS \>= ?) AND (SAP_ORDER.GSTRS \<= ?)

Now though, when the windows pop up, it just says Parameter1 and Parameter2. I would like to customize it to say "Enter the Start Date for your search in the format YYYYMMDD and Enter the End Date for your search in the format YYYYMMDD.
Can anyone help?
I have done hours and hours of reading forum posts and threads and I must be missing some piece of context because nothing seems to work.
I have tried replacing the ? with brackets [] that have the query text in it, and it then gives me a "General ODBC Error" while highlighting the line .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False.
I have tried using Let commands to make parameters and tying them to a cell instead that I could have a user manually enter into before hitting go
I have tried to make parameters separately and using @\[Parameter Name\] to call them into the code in place of the ?.
Any and all help would be appreciated.
'This uses ODBC to query data from SAP based on desired input parameters
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=feodsp1;UID=Genods_rpt;PWD=F3_g3NoDS_R3PorT_2106;DBQ=EH_FEODSP1.WORLD;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSu" _
        ), Array("ccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;STE=F;TSZ=8192;AST=FLOAT;" _
        )), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT SAP_ORDER.ARBPL, SAP_ORDER.NOTIF_NUM, SAP_ORDER.AUFNR, SAP_ORDER.KTEXT, SAP_ORDER.USTXT, SAP_ORDER.GLTRS, SAP_ORDER.GLUZS, SAP_ORDER.GSTRS, SAP_ORDER.GSUZS, SAP_ORDER.AFIH_WAPOS, SAP_ORDER.AFIH" _
        , "_WARPL, SAP_ORDER.WERKS, SAP_ORDER.ZPGGENORDERS_FRAGNETYESNO" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM Z22ODS_GEN.SAP_ORDER SAP_ORDER" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (SAP_ORDER.WERKS='G202') AND (SAP_ORDER.GSTRS Between ? And ?)" _
        )


        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = True
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_feodsp1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     
End With


If you establish the connecttion to your database with ADO using VBA then, you can get the needed values from the user by an InputBox and pass to the SQL command before it is executed. Also, see this link if it helps https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-parameter-query-in-microsoft-query-c67d9af7-c8a0-4bf7-937c-087cb25f7ad3

And, see this link to get the parameter from a cell on the sheet; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-a-parameter-query-addf7cb7-ddf0-442f-a60c-cd7280e201bd#ID0EHD=Newer_versions

@Haluk I had found those links previously and that his how I originally identified using the "?" to feed an input into my SQL code. When I use the brackets though that the first article suggests to customize the prompt I get the ODBC error. The second suggestion doesn't work because it has to be done manually after the query is made to go back and change the parameters to reference a cell. Since my sheet removes the connection and recreates it every time I need to be able to reference a cell within the code itself which is where I am stuck.

It would help to show the code you're using to create and run the query.

Could you return the parameters to variables and then use
" WHERE SAP_ORDER.WERKS='G202' AND SAP_ORDER.GSTRS >= '" & Format(, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND SAP_ORDER.GSTRS <= '" & Format(, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"

@Tim Williams; I guess OP is not using VBA for this. He is using MS Query in the "Data" tab and writing the SQL command text manually. That's why i offered him to use VBA which in this case he could easily get the necessary feed from the user by using the InputBox method.

I am using VBA to create the query using MS query. I will attach the code here

FYI: If able, consider Excel's DB sibling, Access, built for this need without a single line of VBA. Either Linked Table to SAP backend -> Query with named param for user input; or Linked Table -> Form menu for user inputs -> Query with named params.

Unfortunately, I don't believe Access will accomplish what I need. Essentially I need excel due to its graphing capabilities. This project will pull work order data down to suboperations, create a waterfall flow chart for specific time periods color coded by work group that has been filtered and sorted multiple times, and then print it.
